# How to revert back to stock Sprint firmware (Galaxy S7) after installing the wrong one?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, stock-android

I tried to root my Galaxy S7 and failed. Not only did I fail but in the process, I also installed the wrong firmware G930A (ATT) and did not take a backup.

I've been trying to revert back to stock but everytime I try with Odin, I either get a sha256 failed error or a Complete (Write) Error.

I've tried all the sprint firmwares from this site; http://www.theandroidsoul.com/download-galaxy-s7-firmware/#jump-model-no-sm-g930p-sprint None have worked.

I'm using Odin3 v3.12.3.

How can I revert back to the factory stock Sprint firmware for the Galaxy S7 (SM-G930P) after installing the wrong firmware?

Comment: You can give this a try
[Galaxy S7 Stock Firmware](http://www.androidsage.com/2016/05/13/install-sprint-samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-android-6-0-1-marshmallow-firmware-g930pvpu2apd3g935pvpu2apd3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all download the stock firmware for your Samsung Galaxy S7(G930P - Sprint) from [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/98479/G930PVPU2APH7_G930PSPT2APH7_SPR/). But you need to create an account on sammobile website for free by clicking on "Regular Download" button.

To Install the stock Firmware follow the steps below

- Extract (unzip) the firmware file
- Download Odin v3.11.1
- Extract Odin ZIP file
- Open Odin v3.11.1
- Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
- Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
- Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
- Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked
- Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes

Link to Download Firmware: [Galaxy S7 Stock Firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/98479/G930PVPU2APH7_G930PSPT2APH7_SPR/)